# How do I put this code in a function? node.js + mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this line of codes, and I will use it a lot in most of routes, but the think is, it is pretty redundant to write a lot of of the same codes . It's not the best practice. So How do i put it in a function? so that I could use it so many times?

```
// Lines of codes that will be used alot.
    Wardrobe
        .findOne({ owner: req.user._id})
        .populate('items.item')
        .exec(function(err, foundWardrobe) {
          if (err) return next(err);
          console.log(foundCart);

          res.render('main/checkout', {
            wardrobe: foundWardrobe
          });

        });


   // Function to reduce repetitive codes above
    function wardrobe() {

    // What do I put in here? I tried so many codes but didnt work.

    }
```

Comment: is it REST API? can you elaborate more?

Comment: I don't see anything to stop your function extraction. Please provide more detail or one of your failed code.

Answer (score 0):

Parameterize the changable bits:

```
function wardrobe(ownerId, populate, render) {
    Wardrobe
        .findOne({ owner: ownerId})
        .populate(populate)
        .exec(function(err, foundWardrobe) {
          if (err) return next(err);
          console.log(foundCart);

          res.render(render, {
            wardrobe: foundWardrobe
          });

        });
}
```

Then call it:

```
wardrobe(req.user._id, 'items.item', 'main/checkout');
```